# How to separate and arrange firstname from fullname string in C++

Tags: c++

I have:

```
struct student{ 
  string name, 
  float GPA 
};
```

I want to arrange name in alphabetical order ( firstname, if firstname is the same, arrange through lastname );

So I think I need a separateFirstName function and a separateLastName function, but I don't know which value these functions return. If it's a string, how can I use it when I compare ( use it many times)

For example:

```
struct student{ 
    string name, 
    float GPA 
}; 

student Student[n];

void input(student Student[], int n){ ... };
```

Now, I want to arrange Student[i].name ( with i is from 0 to n) in alphabetical order

The first, I'll compare the firstname of Student[i].name, if they're the same, I'll compare the their lastname, if they're still the same, I'll arrange them randomly

for example:

1. Nguyen Nhu Anh
2. So Van Anh
3. Sa Hi Ha
4. Vo Duc Hung Son

So I think I need a separateFirstName function and separateLastName function

```
if string s="Vo Duc Hung Son";
```

then the first name is Son and the last name is Vo

But the thing was, I don't know which value these functions should return. If it's a string, how can I use it when I compare ( use it many times );

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you just sort by `name` alphabetically then you should get the behaviour you require by default, no ?

Comment: Is name contains first name and last name together

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide more detail on you questions. A complete compilable sample showing your problem is step number one. In particular say what the expected outcome is and how it is different from the actual outcome.

Comment: yes, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Name{ 
  string first, 
  string last 
}; 

struct student{ 
  Name name, 
  float GPA 
};
```

Now you can write a function to compare `name.first` and `name.last`

Comment: But the name also has middle name

Comment: then add middle as well in the name struct and compare on that also

Comment: yes, you're right. Thank you. But I just want to input fullname, not firstname, then lastname and middle name

Comment: You can input one string with full name and then you can break it like this `istringstream is(string str_name);    is >> name.first>>name.second>>name.last

Comment: yea, that's good idea. But I dont know how many parts there are in my name. for example Vo Do or Vo Duc Hung or Vo Duc Hung Son,so how can I do like that. I just want to find the way to know the firstname and lastname

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand. But you have string name, for example: name = "Dennis Bond" and you want two strings. firstname = "Dennis" and secondname = "Bond"?

```
void split_name (string name, string& firstname, string& secondname){
    istringstream is(name);
    is >> firstname >> secondname;

}


void split_name (string name, vector<string>& split){
        istringstream is(name);
        string word;

        while (is >> word ) split.push_back(word);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if I do like this, how can I compare Student[i].name ( with i is from 0 to n )

Comment: What about map container?

Comment: Can I ask you another question. I want to improve your split_name function because I dont know how many parts there are in my name. for example Vo Do or Vo Duc Hung or Vo Duc Hung Son. Could you please help me

Comment: I just want to find the way to know the firstname and lastname. for example: if fullname is Vo Duc Hung Son, then firstname is Son and lastname is Vo. But if fullname is Vo Duc Hung, then the firstname is Hung and the lastname is Vo. Could you please help me

Comment: You can do it for example like this:

vector<string> v;
string word;

while (is >> word ) v.push_back(word);